# difference kill -9 pid and kill pid command

Tags: command-line, kill

what is the difference between `kill -9 pid` and `kill pid` command ?
Do they have different behavior ?
i know that -9 is for "SIGKILL" signal

Comment: If you don't specify a signal it will send SIGTERM (giving the process a chance to close itself down gracefully)

Answer (score 6):

`kill pid` (which sends signal 15 (SIGTERM)) tells `pid` to terminate, but said program can execute some code first or even ignore the signal. `kill -9 pid`, on the other hand, forces the program to immediately terminate (it cannot be ignored).

You should always try `kill pid` first, as it allows the program to do things like saving/closing open files before exiting. Only use `kill -9` when you need the program to close and it won't respond to a simple `kill pid`.